# GUI Miner no responses to getwork, and Verification failed

Tags: getwork, verification, error

I just starting with mining today I have everything set up for slush pool on 
GUIMiner - v2012-12-03 .  I'm not sure what is wrong but this is what the console says

```
2013-06-21 01:37:26: Listener for "GPU Miner" started
2013-06-21 01:37:28: Listener for "GPU Miner": stratum.bitcoin.cz:3333 21/06/2013 01:37:28, checking for stratum...
2013-06-21 01:37:28: Listener for "GPU Miner": stratum.bitcoin.cz:3333 21/06/2013 01:37:28, started OpenCL miner on platform 0, device 0 (Juniper)
2013-06-21 01:37:28: Listener for "GPU Miner": stratum.bitcoin.cz:3333 21/06/2013 01:37:28, no response to getwork, using as stratum
2013-06-21 01:37:39: Listener for "GPU Miner": stratum.bitcoin.cz:3333 21/06/2013 01:37:39, Verification failed, check hardware! (0:0:Juniper, a4627d39)
2013-06-21 01:37:51: Listener for "GPU Miner": stratum.bitcoin.cz:3333 21/06/2013 01:37:51, Verification failed, check hardware! (0:0:Juniper, 9fcd8ac2)
2013-06-21 01:37:52: Listener for "GPU Miner": stratum.bitcoin.cz:3333 21/06/2013 01:37:52, Verification failed, check hardware! (0:0:Juniper, 87fcf304)
2013-06-21 01:37:55: Listener for "GPU Miner": stratum.bitcoin.cz:3333 21/06/2013 01:37:55, Verification failed, check hardware! (0:0:Juniper, 5aa4b0f1)!
```

I also took a screenshot of the settings I have chosen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwfvE.png).

Answer (score 2):

An answer can be found on bitcoin talk

https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=177855.msg1852355#msg1852355

Quote from deepceleron on bitcoin talk

> This is your GPU returning invalid hashes from it's kernel. This is
>   because new drivers are crap for older cards.
>
> - Uninstall AMD APP SDK
> - Uninstall AMD Catalyst Install manager: choose "uninstall all software", make sure you have only a VGA driver after restart.
> - Manually remove these files not removed by the installer; any other obvious ATI files with the same file date:
>     C:\Windows\System32\amdocl64.dll   C:\Windows\System32\amdoclcl64.dll 
>     C:\Windows\System32\OpenCL.dll   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\amdocl.dll
>     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\amdoclcl.dll   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\OpenCL.dll
> - Install just the Catalyst 11.11 driver package (no SDK is needed; the AMD APP runtime is included with driver)
> - Mine just a bit slower on your 6870 than a 5830 would.
>
> Better:
>   - use cgminer
>   **- set phatk worksize to 256 and underclock GPU RAM to 300MHz for best power efficiency and higher hashrate**

The big thing to take away from this:
set phatk **worksize to 256** and **underclock GPU RAM to 300MHz** for best power efficiency and higher hashrate

A suggestion i can give you is that bitcointalk can be a great place to find the answer to a lot of off the wall questions related to bitcoin or any alt-coin.